# Testing a node.js server in the same process as the test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am wondering if there is any disadvantage to starting a server in a process and then running tests against that server in the same process.

Obviously there are some performance concerns, but if we are testing accuracy instead of performance, are there any major concerns with code like the following?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var supertest = require('supertest');
var assert = require('assert');

describe('@Test - handleXml()*', function() {

    var self = this;
    var server;
    var payload = ''; // stringified XML
    var xmlPath = path.resolve('test', 'test_data', 'xml_payloads', 'IVR_OnDemandErrorCode.xml');

    before(function(done) {
        var config = self.config = require('univ-config')(module, this.test.parent.title, 'config/test-config');
        server = createServer().on('listening', function() {
            done(null);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        fs.readFile(xmlPath, 'utf8', function(err, content) {
            assert(err == null);
            payload = content;
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should accept request Content-type "text/xml or application/xml"', function(done) {
        supertest(server)
            .post('/event')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/xml')
            .send(payload)
            .expect(200, done);
    });


    it('should transform XML payload into JSON object', function(done) {
        supertest(server)
            .post('/event')
            .set('Content-type', 'application/xml')
            .send(payload)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                assert(err == null,'Error is not null');
                var jsonifiedXml = JSON.parse(res.text);
                assert(typeof jsonifiedXml === 'object','jsonifiedXml not an object');
                done();
            });

    });

    describe('JSONified XML', function() {

        it('should have proper key casing', function(done) {

            supertest(server)
                .post('/event')
                .set('Content-type', 'application/xml')
                .send(payload)
                .expect(200)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    assert(err == null);
                    var payload = JSON.parse(res.text);
                    payload = payload.events[0].data;
                    assert(payload.hasOwnProperty('ppv'),'Bad value for ppv');
                    assert(payload.hasOwnProperty('mac'),'Bad value for mac');
                    assert(payload.hasOwnProperty('appName'),'Bad value for appName');
                    assert(payload.hasOwnProperty('divisionId'),'Bad value for divisionId');
                    assert(payload.hasOwnProperty('callTime'),'Bad value for callTime');
                    assert(payload.hasOwnProperty('callDate'),'Bad value for callDate');
                    assert(payload.hasOwnProperty('ivrLOB'),'Bad value for ivrLOB');

                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});


function createServer(opts) {

    //Note: this is a good pattern, definitely

    var handleXml = require(path.resolve('lib', 'handleXml'));

    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        handleXml(req, res, function(err) {
            res.statusCode = err ? (err.status || 500) : 200;
            res.end(err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(req.body));
        });
    });

    server.listen(5999);  //TODO: which port should this be listening on? a unused port, surely

    return server;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the standard way of testing a the http endpoints in a node application. But you are not going to want to have a createServer() function in each test. You will have a common function that creates a server that you can use through out your application, including to start the production server.

You right in noticing the having the server listen to a port doesn't actually do anything for you.

For this reason, it's common to have what I call an application factory that starts everything about a server, but does not listen to a port.  That way I can access the server from a test or a script.  The production app gets booted from a minimal index file:

```
var createServer = require('./AppFactory');
var server = createServer();
server.listen(5999);
```